# Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be continuous and $X$ be compact. Then $f(X)\subseteq Y$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-explanation, compactness

Proof: Let $\{V_\alpha\}$ be an open cover of $f(X)$. Let $U_\alpha=f^{-1}(V_\alpha)$. By compactness, $X$ has a finite subcover $U_1,..., U_n$. Therefore, $V_1,..., V_n$ cover $f(X)$.

The proof is very simple, although I'm having problems understanding why we can let $f^{-1}$ be defined on $\{V_\alpha\}$? From what I understood about functions, $f^{-1}$ should only defined on a subset of $Y$. But since, any $V_\alpha$ is not necessarily contained in $Y$, then we can't map $V_\alpha$ to $X$ with $f^{-1}$. Correct?

Comment: Since $V_\alpha \subset f(X) \subset Y$, we indeed have $V_\alpha$ is contained in $Y$.

Comment: What you really want to prove is that $f(X)$ with the subspace topology is compact.  So, to start, you would actually need to find $W_\alpha \subseteq Y$ which are open in $Y$ and such that $V_\alpha = f(X) \cap W_\alpha$, and set $U_\alpha = f^{-1}(W_\alpha)$.  Then yadda yadda yadda, and you need to prove $V_{\alpha_1}, \ldots, V_{\alpha_n}$ cover $f(X)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: I agree, but how do you find $W_\alpha$ or how do you construct it? The proof doesn't seem to have constructed anything.

Comment: @Andrew: I don't agree that $V_\alpha$ is contained in $f(X)$.

Comment: @TheLastCipher Definition of subspace topology - since each $V_\alpha$ is a subset of $f(X)$ which is open in the subspace topology, by definition there exists $W_\alpha$ an open subset of $Y$ such that $V_\alpha = f(X) \cap W_\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An open cover of $f(X)$ is a family of open subsets $V_\alpha$ in $Y$ such that
$$
f(X)\subseteq\bigcup_{\alpha}V_\alpha
$$
You can certainly consider $f^{-1}(V_\alpha)$ (see final note 1) and, by elementary properties of the inverse image operation,
$$
X\subseteq\bigcup_\alpha f^{-1}(V_\alpha) \tag{1}
$$
By compactness of $X$, there are $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ so that
$$
X\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^n f^{-1}(V_{\alpha_i}) \tag{2}
$$
(see final note 2). This implies that
$$
f(X)\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_{\alpha_i}
$$
with an easy verification.

#### Final notes.

1. The set $f^{-1}(V_\alpha)$ could well be empty, if $V_\alpha$ doesn't intersect $f(X)$, but it's not relevant as far as the proof is concerned.
2. In the displays $(1)$ and $(2)$, $\subseteq$ could be replaced by $=$, but actually the same argument shows that

   > *if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a continuous function and $C$ is a compact subset of $X$, then $f(C)$ is compact.*

   so it's better to have $\subseteq$.

Comment: So $f^{-1}(V_\alpha)$ is the set of elements of $X$ that maps to $f(X)\cap V_\alpha$? (I think I need to revisit my elementary set theory. lol)

Comment: @TheLastCipher $f^{-1}(V)=\{x\in X:f(x)\in V\}$.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong when yuo assert that $V_\alpha$ is not necessarily contained in $Y$. After all, the set of all $V_\alpha$ is an open cover of $Y$. Besides, $f^{-1}(V)$ is the inverse image of $V$.

Comment: The picture I have in mind is that the elements of $\{V_\alpha\}$ all intersect $f(X)$ in such a way that it "covers" $f(X)$ so each element of $\{V_\alpha\}$ is not necessarily contained in $f(X)$. And I don't understand why $\{V_\alpha\}$ would cover $Y$ since $f(X)$, that which is being covered, is not necessarily equal to $Y$.